# How to insert data to TableView in another view controller Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`. I make a network call in `ViewControllerB`,when it success,I want to insert a data to the `TableView` in `ViewControllerA`,so the data can appear as 1st item in the `TableView`.

**Here is what I tried:**

**ViewControllerB**

```
 var myItem = [Item]() //here is the array in ViewControllerA

Alamofire.request(MyURL!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON{
            response in

            switch response.result{
            case .success(let result):

                let json = JSON(result)

                if let myJson = json.dictionary,let myItem = Item.init(dict: myJson){
                    self.myItem.insert(newPost, at: 0)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: nil) //here I call notification center after insert to the array

                   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                   self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 //back to ViewControllerA
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print("error = \(error)")
            }

        }
```

**In ViewControllerA (which contain the tableView)**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateTableView), name: .reload, object: nil)
   }  

@objc func updateTableView(_ notification: Notification){
        print("here get called")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

**I create an extension for the NotificationCenter**

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let reload = Notification.Name("reloadTableView")
}
```

After done all this,the item that I insert to the array of `ViewControllerB` didnt appear in the 1st place of `TableView` in `ViewControllerB`.

I make a print in `updateTableView()` function which will call when received response from `NotificationCenter` in `ViewControllerA`,it get called,but the data is not appear.

I cant use segue,cause the both ViewController are 2 of the tab in TabbarController.

So in this case,how can I insert the data from `ViewControllerB` to `TableView` of `ViewControllerA`?

Comment: is there a common array for ViewController A and B ? Did you checked with breakpoints that do TableView in Controller A reloads when notification is post ? Try checking Array is It updated ?

Comment: common array is that mean,I define the array which use for tableView in ViewController A? In my question `var myItem = [Item]()` <--this is used for tableView in ViewControllerA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new array by this line

```
var myItem = [Item]()
```

But the viewControllerA use the different array. Try to send a new array in notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: self.myItem)
```

Then in viewControllerA set the new array.

```
@objc func updateTableView(_ notification: Notification){
        var newItems = notification.object as! [Item]

        arrayOfControllerA.append(contentsOf: newItems)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Comment: bro I didnt use segue,cause is the TabbarController.So how to access the array in ViewControllerA?

Comment: Ok, then you could post the notification with this array, I edited the answer

Comment: Your answer is posting the notification in ViewControllerB,can you show me how to get the array in ViewControllerA as well?

Comment: So when I get the array in ViewControllerA,is it I insert this array to array in the existing array in ViewControllerA?

Comment: I got this error `Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.Item' (0x100ccd9a0) to 'NSArray' (0x1b4ced950).` Can u help?

Comment: Use self.myItem  when post notification